# How can I wrap two rows at once / together?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have multiple pairs of rows of text. 
I want that each pair of rows wrap together, and each character always stays above or below its counterpart, without sliding right or left.

Example: a songbook (my use-case)

> **`E-              A#           G#7/9`**
>      `these are the lyrics of my song`
>              **`Db             E-`**
>  `if chords offset it's super-wrong`

**Is there a general / simple solution?**

*Since posting this question I found a way which requires a heavy use of the figure space (a [non-breaking space](https://mailtrap.io/blog/nbsp/), code: `&numsp`, result: > <). It's not general nor simple, but it's better than nothing, so I posted it below, as an answer ([click here to jump to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71451592/18430361)).*

Comment: Pinch to zoom will scale the entire page. You can zoom in by using the browser zoom buttons.

Comment: I think your question would be easier to understand if there was anything resembling chords and lyrics in the markup. Please provide that. You don't have to use actual text, but at least use generic terms.

Comment: Hi. I just improved the layout of your question a bit. It's already quite good but "does not work" isn't sufficiently clear. What happens instead?

Comment: Ty. I edited, it seems more clear to me what does not work and what happens instead. Is it good?

Comment: Oh, it's clear and focused now. Maybe you are ready to add some research? Have you searched for a solution? What did you get? Maybe add a paragraph at the end describing what you found. That would make the question even better.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: the following is NOT a general solution, because it requires a heavy use of the figure space (a [non-breaking space](https://mailtrap.io/blog/nbsp/), code: `&numsp`, result: > <). 
Fiddle with it here: https://onecompiler.com/html/3xwdbhck4

```css
/* FUNCTIONAL CSS: needed to couple chords-lyrics */
.page {
  position: absolute;        /* prevents decoupling when wrapping */
  width: 96%;
}
.chords, .lyrics {
  white-space: pre-wrap;     /* whitespace collapse OFF, line breaks ON */
  font-family: monospace;    /* keeps chords-lyrics aligned */
  font-size: 12pt;           /* keeps chords-lyrics aligned (any value works) */
  margin-right: 2pt;         /* keeps chords-lyrics aligned (any value works) */
  line-height: 2.4;          /* makes room for the lines of the other div */
  margin-top: 0pt;           /* must be 0 or the divs will offset */
}
.chords {
  position: absolute;        /* makes .lyrics elements overlap */
}
.lyrics {
  padding-top: 14pt;         /* shifts the rows of text, must equal font-size of .chords */
  /*position: relative;      /* puts .lyrics behind .chords, not recommended */
}


/* DEBUG CSS: it helps visualizing telements */
.songs  { background-color: #eee; }
summary { background-color: #ddd; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<div class="page">

<div>
  <b>EXPLANATION</b><br>
  With this setup the common space (the spacebar space) allows the browser to break the line.<br>
  You can prevent unwanted wrapping by <b>replacing the common space with a figure space</b>, which is a 
  non-breaking space (NBSP) and does not allow the browser to break the line. Use the code <b>&ampnbsp</b>. 
  (I personally prefer to use the output of &ampnbsp in my html, but it's risky, since it's invisible)<br><br>
  In your case you want to use the &ampnbsp above or below any visible character. Check this example:
</div> <!--songs-->
<br>

<div class="songs">
  <details open>
    <summary>(A) Song with standard spaces and UNDERSCOREs, to visualize the chunks</summary>
    <div class="chords">Em_____ ___ ____A#____ __ __ G#7/9 __ ______ ___Db_ ____ _____ E____</div>
    <div class="lyrics">__these are the lyrics of my song, if chords offset it's super-wrong</div>
    <div class="chords">___ __ __size ___ ___dow_ blank ___ _chor___ ______ ___ sli__</div>
    <div class="lyrics">try to resize the window, _____ the "chords" should not slide</div>
  </details>
</div>
<br>

<div>If you replace the UNDERSCOREs in (A) this is the output:</div>
<br>

<div class="songs">
  <details open>
    <summary>(B) Song with standard and FIGURE SPACEs in the right chunks</summary>
    <div class="chords">Em              A#           G#7/9              Db             E    </div>
    <div class="lyrics">  these are the lyrics of my song, if chords offset it's super-wrong</div>
    <div class="chords">         size        dow  blank      chor               sli  </div>
    <div class="lyrics">try to resize the window,       the "chords" should not slide</div>
  </details>
</div>
<br>

<div class="songs">
  <details>
    <summary>WRONG) Song with only standard SPACEs</summary>
    <div class="chords">Em              A#           G#7/9              Db             Em   </div>
    <div class="lyrics">  these are the lyrics of my song, if chords offset it's super-wrong</div>
    <div class="chords">         size        dow  blank            the          sli  </div>
    <div class="lyrics">try to resize the window,       you'll see the "chords" slide</div>
  </details>
</div>
  
  </div>
```